# Do you know how to visualize a DXF files in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dxf

I want to display DXF files (2D mechanical drawings) in my react app. I cant find the way to do it. Thank You!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the package i used once for this https://www.npmjs.com/package/dxf-viewer